# How to build openCV with GTK support on Mac

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I pip installed `opencv-python` in python3.6 on my mac.
`import cv2` works fine, except when I tried to do `cv2.imshow()`, it says 
`OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support`
Can someone give me a specific walk through about how to do rebuild the library please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the [PyPi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python)?

(emphasis added)

> **IMPORTANT NOTE**
>
> MacOS and Linux wheels have currently some limitations:
>
> - video related functionality is not supported (not compiled with FFmpeg)
> - for example `cv2.imshow()` **will not work** (not compiled with GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support)

So, you are welcome to [compile it yourself](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python), I guess, but even [those builds are listed as failing](https://travis-ci.org/skvark/opencv-python).

You could use `homebrew` to install `opencv`, though not sure how that's compiled

Comment: I see. Thx! but how do I compile it by myself?? I didn't find it in the link

Comment: As stated, use homebrew http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/